# NuxtJS and Firebase Web SDK Beta v9: How to add realtime listener to firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am using the new Firebase Web SDK v9 (beta 8) with NuxtJS2. I have a child component that allows a user to edit his post data. This updates a document in Firestsore with the new post changes. However, my question is...how do I get have my parent component get realtime updates of this new data?

Let me explain:

I have the following example components structure in the app:

```
<PostCardDetail>
    <PostEdit />
</PostCardDetail>
```

`PostCardDetail.vue` script section where I am doing the data fetch:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase'
export default {
  name: 'PostCardDetail',
  data() {
    return {
      post: {}
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const docRef = doc(db, 'posts', this.$route.params.postId)
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
    this.post = docSnap.data()
  },
  mounted () {
    // I believe I will need to mount the realtime listener here?
  },
}
</script>
```

The `PostEdit.vue` script section where I am doing the data editing:

```
editPost() {
    const postRef = doc(db, 'posts', this.post.id)
    await updateDoc(postRef, {
          ...editedPost,
          updatedAt: serverTimestamp()
        })
        console.log('updated!')
        this.$store.dispatch('edit', false)
        alert('Post successfully updated!')
}
```

I am able to successfully edit the data, but to view the latest changes, I need to manually refresh the browser. How can I get automatic real time update with firestore after post is edited by user? I assume this listener will be in the mounted() hook property of `PostCardDetail`?

My attempt:

```
  mounted() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, 'posts', this.$route.params.postId),
      (snapshot) => {
        this.post = snapshot.data()
      }
    )
  }
```

This SEEMS to work OK, but feels a bit clunky. Is this the recommended way to approach this with NuxtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks perfectly fine and similar to as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-v9).

> I assume this listener will be in the mounted() hook property of PostCardDetail

Ideally you might want to set the listener *once* the component is created and I've mostly seen listeners being set in `created()`

```js
created() {
  const unsub = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, 'posts', this.$route.params.postId),
      (snapshot) => {
        this.post = snapshot.data()
      }
    )
}
```

To use the `unsub` somewhere else, you can set it in the data property or pass it to other components depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks. Don't I have to unsubscribe from it to save bandwidth if the component is no longer needed? For example, on page navigation away , should I unsubscribe somewhere?

Comment: @redshift yes you should.